# CSS doesnt load properly when struts 2 jquery tree plugin is used

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

I'm using struts2 jquery tree plugin to show a tree in a div . 
The problem is that either the CSS of the tree or the CSS of my JSP page doesn't load properly.

I tried to change the order in which the scripts load and now I can see that all my CSS on the JSP is as required but the tree is not loaded with proper CSS .

As of now I've set the `jqueryui="true"` in the`<sj:head>`.

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true"  />    
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>       
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myscript.js" ></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Test.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script>

$.subscribe('treeClicked', function(event, data) {
      var item = event.originalEvent.data.rslt.obj;
      alert('Clicked ID : ' + item.attr("id") + ' - Text ' + item.text());
});
</script>
<body>
     <s:url var="treeDataUrl" action="GetData"/>
                            <sjt:tree 
                                    id="jsonTree" 
                                    href="%{treeDataUrl}"
                                    onClickTopics="treeClicked" 
                                    jstreetheme="default"
                            />
</body>
```

Note: I need to include all the CSS files ive mentioned in the code. They are necessary for my UI

Comment: You have to post your code, otherwise we cannot understand you

Comment: ive added some code ,please refer to that

Comment: what you mean css not loaded proper? please try to upload a screenshot! ps: there is `no attr called 'theme' for sjt, there is only the attr 'jstreetheme'`

Comment: Thank you .
That was the real problem indeed .
The css of the tree did not load properly because it could not find the jstreetheme attribute.
Fixed it .! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Jaiwo99 -- please help me in one more thing .

onClickTopics="treeClicked" doesnt work even when i implemented the method. Any suggestions?
ive updated the code . This is the code given in the showcase
[link](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action#jsp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I collect your problems:
1. The attribute of jquery-ui-theme should be `jstreetheme`, `NOT theme`
2. your script would not be called on page load! change it to:

```
$(function(){
    alert("ECHO..."); // check if script called on page load
    $.subscribe('treeClicked', function(event, data) {
        var item = event.originalEvent.data.rslt.obj;
        alert('Clicked ID : ' + item.attr("id") + ' - Text ' + item.text());
    });
});
```

Comment: There is no change even if i put code on load as you suggested.

and ive changed the theme attribute .There is no problem with that

Comment: @phani try add `alert()` to your script, check your script executed or not.

Comment: i tried to put alerts , but no luck . 

The work around for that was to implement the listeners in the classic jquery style , but i could not use the onClickTopics attribute .

The code i tried was 
     ``$(".jstree ul li").live('click',function(){
    <br>alert("click on tree node");
    ``});``

Comment: @phani no, i mean try to check if `$.subscribe();` called on your page, check my change

Comment: i can see the alert , but the subscribe doesnt work . I checked the source and i can see that the subscribe script file is loaded .

Comment: @phani errrrrrrrrr.. which version of struts2 are you using, which version of struts2-jquery-tree-plugin are you using

Comment: struts2 - 2.3.1
struts2-jquery plugin - 3.4.0

Comment: im sorry i didnot include the tree plugin version , it is 3.5.1

Comment: @phani I'd like to suggest you to use the same version of this plug, change your version of plugins to `3.5.1` could avoid more problems

Comment: even that didnt work out . I updated the jar versions to 3.5.1 , both struts2-jquery and also the tree plugin

Answer (score 0):

Now, I'm doing my project with jquery struts2.
I can call my javascript method when I click on a tree node, so I would like to share my experience.

Pls, write this in sjt tree tag

> onClickTopics="treeClicked"

And then write in script tag

```
$(function(){
$.subscribe('treeClicked', function (event, data){
        // check if script called on page load
        alert("treeClicked");
        //Get the next item, this is the tree node object is selected, many operations need it
        var item = event.originalEvent.data.rslt.obj;
        //Other code written here
        //For example, we want to select the node id suggest, you can write like this
        alert ('Clicked ID : ' + item.attr ("id"));
});
});
```

I hope my answer will help you.